# Allow document creation in firebase depending on the document count in the collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to create a firebase rule that allow to create documents in a collection if the number of documents in that collection hasn't reached a max ?

Something like this :
doc:

```
/databases/{database}/documents/activities/activity :
{
    "max_users": 10
}
```

rules:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents/activities/activity/participants/{userUid} {
    allow create if [doc_count] < [max_users];
}
```